# USPS Create Shipping Label checkbox doesn't show on Ship Order screen

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, labels, usps

I'm running Magento 2.2.7. I have both UPS and USPS accounts with the API account information added in and in Production mode.

I have successfully added UPS, retrieve rates on checkout, and can process an order shipment with the checkbox to Create Shipping Label.

However, viewing an order that has USPS as the shipping method, will not show Create Shipping Label checkbox on the Order's Ship screen. I have tried just about everything, and I believe the USPS account is in production mode. I've not been able to locate anyone talking about this as an issue. Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Excerpt from the [Magento 2.2.3 release notes](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.3CE.html):

> On February 23, 2018, USPS removed APIs that support the creation of shipping labels without postage. In response, we’ve removed this functionality from the Magento Admin.

See also

- Magento 2.2 [commit 3c4cb60](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/3c4cb609ba14362b209ce4d0c7cc2b82c97207d2)
- Magento 2.3 [commit 6efad83](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/6efad8374df63ba77c8b44c7d278a57a60b95124)
- `\Magento\Usps\Model\Carrier`

```php
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 * Starting from 23.02.2018 USPS doesn't allow to create free shipping labels via their API.
 */
public function isShippingLabelsAvailable()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I see. So even though we have an API account and would like create postage and be charged for it thru our account, the out of box Magento USPS module will no longer do that? It seems to suggest, we need to just find another 3rd party shipping module. We were able to use Stamps.com to now print postage and get rates. But unfortunate that we can't use it thru our normal USPS account, despite having a CC on that account to pay for the postage.