# Unable to create shipping label (USPS) in magento2.4.5

Tags: magento2.4.5

In magento order shipment page not showing create shipping label(USPS). Any one please help me how to use USPS in magento2.4.5

Shipping method: USPS

Note: In the carrier.php i found the below notes.
**Starting from 23.02.2018 USPS doesn't allow to create free shipping labels via their API.**

Comment: Please check the answer of https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/265570/usps-create-shipping-label-checkbox-doesnt-show-on-ship-order-screen

Comment: @CharmiPatel already i reviewed this url. Can you please tell USPS support for magento2.4.5?